# M2: How to change standard link to redirect new customer account

Tags: magento2, customer

I want change link  which redirect to form "Register customer account" to own link

in `module-customer`  I changed `newcustomer.phtml`

From:

```
        <div class="primary">
            <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getCreateAccountUrl()) ?>" class="action create primary"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Create an Account')) ?></span></a>
```

to:

```
<a href="marketplace/seller/register/" class="action create primary"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Create an Account')) ?></span></a>
            </div>
```

But after save link redirect wrong, to:

```
https://domain.com/en/customer/account/login/marketplace/seller/register/
```

should be:

```
https://domain.com/en/marketplace/seller/register/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to get URL in phtml file

```
<?php echo $block->getUrl('marketplace/seller/register/'); ?>
```

you code should be as below

```
<a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('marketplace/seller/register/'); ?>" class="action create primary"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Create an Account')) ?></span></a>
```

Why url redirect to

> https://domain.com/en/customer/account/login/marketplace/seller/register/

because you have not added slash in beginning, you can also use code as below:

```
<a href="/marketplace/seller/register/" class="action create primary"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Create an Account')) ?></span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put the whole link instead otherwise the `marketplace/seller/register/`  will only append to the original link.

```
<a href="https://domain.com/en/marketplace/seller/register/" class="action create primary"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Create an Account')) ?></span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use getUrl() function of the block. So you can write your code as below. This will fix your issue.

```
    <div class="primary">
        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('marketplace/seller/register')) ?>" class="action create primary"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Create an Account')) ?></span></a>
```

I hope this'll help you.